# Trying to get Jupyter Notebook 5.1 Running (keeps running 4.2.1)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I did a "pip3 install --upgrade notebook" to get the latest version of Jupyter notebook (5.1.0).  The installation went fine, but when I launch "jupyter notebook" from the terminal and then go into "help>about" it is still running 4.2.1  Can someone tell me how to launch the new version?

**Jupyter Notebook HELP>ABOUT**

[image: Jupyter Notebook HELP>ABOUT screenshot]

**Screenshot showing terminal to launch Jupyter Notebook**

[image: Screenshot showing terminal to launch Jupyter Notebook]

Comment: You used `pip3 install` but you start it from a python2 environment? That seems like a possible source of the problem.

Comment: How can I start it from the python3 environment?

Comment: I don't know. It's your environment. Check the documentation of whatever distribution you use (Canopy, right?).

Comment: I fixed the problem.  I went into Canopy and it was set to be my default Python environment.  I set it not to be the default in the Canopy preferences.  Once I did that and launched Jupyter Notebook, it ran the new version.  Thanks!