# Unable to get Jupyter Notebook Running After Many Attempts

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

After many attempts since last week I have been unable to run Jupyter notebook or Lab. I used to run from VS Code from Windows 11 and have many .ipynb files, and without me doing anything atypical that I know about, I now cannot connect to a kernel to run one cell of Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately I am not strong at computing where I have been able to troubleshoot.  The kernel waits very long periods of time to connect before timing out. After many searches, I have tried a handful of fixes from other posts but have been unsuccessful.

1. I have restarted VS Code and my computer without any success. I also tried to open a new notebook session on Jupyter Lab (`jupyter lab`) and Jupyter notebook (`jupyter`) and run a simple `print('hello world')` cell but it still hung up for at least 10 minutes on each attempt and did not connect to a kernel.
2. Following recommendations on SO and elsewhere, I tried to uninstall and reinstall Jupyter using, for uninstall:
   `python -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat jupyterlab-widgets nbclient`
   and reinstall using:
   `pip install jupyterlab`.
   This did not help.
3. Following another recommendation, I created a virtual environment, reisntalled jupyter, and tried to launch a notebook instance and still had the same problem.
4. I tried upgrading jupyter per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255548/trying-to-get-jupyter-notebook-5-1-running-keeps-running-4-2-1).
5. [This solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509993/vs-code-using-jupyter-connecting-to-kernel-python-3-6-9-waiting-for-jupyter-s) and many others seem to be related to updating one of the packages to a new version. I have tried a handful of these but have had no success; unfortunately I didn't keep track of all of them.
6. I followed the guidelines from [Issue 9014](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9014) but it doesn't seem to apply as I don't know how I can still have an active session open after all of the troubleshooting.

I would be very appreciative if anyone could provide some help. I am a few hours into this and have already started converting all of my notebook files to .py scripts since I am worried I won't be able to resolve this issue.

I'm running:

- Python 3.9.1 64-bit

At this point, I cannot run Jupyter at all from VS code or from the command line due to it failing to connect for virtually unlimited periods of time.  6 troubleshooting steps I've taken are included in the 'Details of the problem' section.

In Jupyter notebook, it is stuck on:

> 'Kernel starting, please wait...".

In VS Code, it is stuck on:

> Connecting to kernel: Python 3.9.1 64-bit: Activating Python Environment 'Python 3.9.1 64-bit'

The command line output copied from my last attempt is below:

```
PS C:\Users\wbpla\OneDrive\python_work\cbb> jupyter lab
c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.182 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-11-06 08:57:57.198 ServerApp] The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None.
[W 2022-11-06 08:57:57.214 ServerApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.214 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.214 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\wbpla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.214 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\wbpla\OneDrive\python_work\cbb
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.6.4 is running at:
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=7ba9196b42de16070141cce6550ff5b7f27917e959997a71
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=7ba9196b42de16070141cce6550ff5b7f27917e959997a71
[I 2022-11-06 08:57:57.417 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2022-11-06 08:57:57.464 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/wbpla/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-12584-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=7ba9196b42de16070141cce6550ff5b7f27917e959997a71
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=7ba9196b42de16070141cce6550ff5b7f27917e959997a71
c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.206 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.214 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.275 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.281 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.317 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.335 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.370 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.370 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.436 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.452 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.858 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:01.870 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.071 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.131 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.160 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.190 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.240 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.513 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[I 2022-11-06 08:58:02.675 LabApp] Build is up to date
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.852 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.862 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.917 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.932 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.948 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.963 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:02.995 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.010 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.073 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.073 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.385 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.401 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.557 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.604 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.635 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.666 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:03.713 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.010 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.058 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cfb/CFB_Daily_Run.ipynb?content=0&1667746682691 (::1): No such file or directory: cfb/CFB_Daily_Run.ipynb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.058 ServerApp] No such file or directory: cfb/CFB_Daily_Run.ipynb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.060 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cfb/CFB_Daily_Run.ipynb?content=0&1667746682691 (::1) 3.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.060 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cbb/Untitled.ipynb?content=0&1667746682690 (::1): No such file or directory: cbb/Untitled.ipynb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.060 ServerApp] No such file or directory: cbb/Untitled.ipynb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.061 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cbb/Untitled.ipynb?content=0&1667746682690 (::1) 3.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.156 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cfb?1667746684153 (::1): No such file or directory: cfb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.157 ServerApp] No such file or directory: cfb
[W 2022-11-06 08:58:04.158 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/cfb?1667746684153 (::1) 1.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[I 2022-11-06 08:58:07.156 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 2022-11-06 08:58:07.473 ServerApp] Kernel started: 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:07.529 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:14.972 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:14.972 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:14.972 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:20.110 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:20.110 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:20.110 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:25.220 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:27.152 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:27.152 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:32.215 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:32.215 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:32.215 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:37.285 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:37.285 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:37.285 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:42.362 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:42.363 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:42.364 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:47.466 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:47.466 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:47.466 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:52.568 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:52.568 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:52.568 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:57.663 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:57.664 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 08:59:57.664 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:02.742 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:02.742 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:02.743 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:07.798 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:07.798 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:07.799 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a
[I 2022-11-06 09:00:08.169 ServerApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
[E 2022-11-06 09:00:10.423 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c39e52f0-4e25-491c-a0ee-d9a668a8138f (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c39e52f0-4e25-491c-a0ee-d9a668a8138f', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 944, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
    asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout
[E 2022-11-06 09:00:10.423 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c240751f-ce98-4f52-959e-f9fa0ab8be43 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c240751f-ce98-4f52-959e-f9fa0ab8be43', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 944, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
    asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout
[E 2022-11-06 09:00:10.423 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c23fc1b0-d9e3-43dd-b9cc-6e4ce03fa517 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a/channels?session_id=c23fc1b0-d9e3-43dd-b9cc-6e4ce03fa517', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 944, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
    asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:10.423 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a:c39e52f0-4e25-491c-a0ee-d9a668a8138f
[W 2022-11-06 09:00:10.735 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a:c240751f-ce98-4f52-959e-f9fa0ab8be43
[E 2022-11-06 09:00:40.406 ServerApp] Exception in callback <bound method WebSocketMixin.send_ping of ZMQChannelsHandler(8c5cd803-d514-424c-9345-dc9cc6600c8a)>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 921, in _run
        val = self.callback()
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 184, in send_ping
        self.ping(b'')
      File "c:\users\wbpla\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 444, in ping
        raise WebSocketClosedError()
    tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
[W 2022-11-06 09:01:10.422 ServerApp] WebSocket ping timeout after 120007 ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running

```
conda update conda
```

before

```
conda update --all
```

To resolve all dependency conflicts. The issue is only due to conflict of extensions of jupyter lab